# Difference between using (j,i) vs (i,j) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

So I have this code, where my response Shrinkage is affected by 5 variables namely ORT,LT,PBT,RA and L. I am plotting a surface for response when 2 variables vary while others are constant. I am getting the wrong graph when i use (i,j) while defining the shrinkage. This problem is solved when i use (j,i) instead of (i,j). I wish to know why this is happening.

```
ORT=0:1.8:90;
LT=100:4:300;
PBT=54;
RA=0;
L=50;
i=1;
j=1;
Shrinkage=zeros(50,50);
for i=1:50
 for j=1:50
  Shrinkage***(i,j)***=-0.610-(0.000653*ORT(i))+(0.002238 *LT(j))-
  (0.000255*RA)+(0.00497*L)+(0.01411*PBT)+(0.000003*ORT(i)*LT(j))-
  (0.000044*LT(j)*PBT)-(0.000009*RA*RA)-(0.000001*LT(j)*LT(j))-
  (0.000011*L*L)+(0.000010*ORT(i)*L)+(0.000007*RA*L)-(0.000078*PBT*L);
 end
end
A=linspace(0,90,50);
B=linspace(100,300,50);
[ORT,LT]=meshgrid(A,B);
surfc(ORT,LT,Shrinkage);
```

Comment: That's because of the `meshgrid` call.  It has nothing to do with the way the indexing of `(i,j)` works.  The `ORT` and `LT` coordinates are flipped when you created the grid of coordinates.  Replace `meshgrid` with `ndgrid` and you can leave the `(i,j)` indexing the same and it'll solve your problem.  You can also reverse the order of `ORT` and `LT` in the `meshgrid` call as well: `[LT, ORT] = meshgrid(A, B);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with Matrix Indices vs. Axis Indices.

Pay attention when you use this or that (`meshgrid` vs. `ndgrid`).